# I am trying to implement a template into rails to test it out but I can't get bootstrap to work with the index page. Any advice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**application.css**

```
*
 *= require business-casual
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
```

everything is in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `stylesheets`

**application.html.erb**

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Here's the repo- https://github.com/robschwartz/toolbelt

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: what exactly is "not working?"

Comment: please post your Gemfile

Comment: my html page isn't recognizing the css at all